# Resize superview with autolayout depending on largest subview

Tags: swift, cocoa, autolayout, nsview, nslayoutconstraint

What is the best practice to resize superview with autolayout if we have inner `NSView` columns with dynamic heights?

For example. If we have two column layout, where left column height is bigger than right column, the superview height should be as right column height. Than, if we change right column height to be bigger than left column height, superview height should change to height of right column. How to accomplish this?

I made sample project to test this:

1. Initially we have layout with two columns, where `.Bottom` constraint of left `NSView` is attached to bottom of superview.

[image: Initial state]

2. If we press `Make Right Bigger` button, I make height of right `NSView` bigger than left one.

[image: Final state]

So I want here superview to change height depending on bigger column (right column). Is there a good practice to do so?

Code:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    let leftView = NSView()
    let rightView = NSView()
    let button = NSButton()

    var rightViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override func loadView() {
        self.view = TestView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        leftView.backgroundColor = NSColor.redColor()
        rightView.backgroundColor = NSColor.orangeColor()

        layoutLeft(view, insertView: leftView)
        layoutRight(view, insertView: rightView)

        button.title = "Make Right Bigger"
        button.target = self
        button.action = "makeBigger:"
        ViewControllerLayout.layoutBotton(view, insertView: button, bottom: -20)
    }

    func makeBigger(sender: AnyObject) {
        rightViewHeightConstraint?.animator().constant = 150.0
    }

    func layoutLeft(containerView: NSView, insertView: NSView) {
        insertView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        containerView.addSubview(insertView)

        let c1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: insertView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let c2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: insertView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0.0)
        let c3 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: insertView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100.0)
        let c4 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: insertView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let c5 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: insertView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -60.0)

        containerView.addConstraint(c1)
        containerView.addConstraint(c2)
        containerView.addConstraint(c3)
        containerView.addConstraint(c4)
        containerView.addConstraint(c5)
    }

    func layoutRight(containerView: NSView, insertView: NSView) {
        insertView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        containerView.addSubview(insertView)

        let c1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: insertView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let c2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: insertView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0.0)
        let c3 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: insertView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50.0)
        let c4 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: insertView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let c5 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: insertView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -60.0)

        containerView.addConstraint(c1)
        containerView.addConstraint(c2)
        containerView.addConstraint(c3)
        containerView.addConstraint(c4)
        // containerView.addConstraint(c5) // Cant add .Bottom constraint here, because of different column sizes.

        rightViewHeightConstraint = c3
    }
}

struct ViewControllerLayout {

    static func layoutBotton(containerView: NSView, insertView: NSView, bottom: Double) {
        insertView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        containerView.addSubview(insertView)

        containerView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: insertView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
        containerView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: insertView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: CGFloat(bottom)))
    }
}
```

Download test project: [GitHub](https://github.com/Dimeg/test-osx-autolayout-resize-superview)

Comment: Do you get any callbacks when height of views change?

Comment: One way is to register `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "viewDidResize:", name: NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification, object: self)` notification for column views. Than I could calculate and change height of superview manually. But maybe it is possible to recreate such behaviour with constraints only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to accomplish this with constraints only. Just added the container view for columns and set its height as `GreaterThanOrEqual` to left column and right column.

```
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: leftView, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: rightView, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a constraint on superview with height

```
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: greaterHeightAmongTwoColumns)
```

As discussed in the comment, you can post a notification and then let the super view know the updated frame. Super view would check if the updated height of any of the two columns is greater than its current height and update its heightConstraint declared above and then call

```
[self layoutIfNeeded]
```

on the superview's superview so that it is laid out with the new frame.